# What's the Italian equivalent for "hiring managers"?

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage, translation, word-choice

I have researched this a bit and have not found the right translation. The closest I've got was "managers di assunzione" in plural or "dirigenti per l'assunzione".

Hiring managers or line managers are technical and administrative managers (not HR) also responsible for making the final decision to hire a job candidate. They belong to the "hiring personnel" supergroup and may delegate the tedious task of short-listing candidates to HR, head hunters or recruiters. Hiring managers are the future "would be" your boss basically.

If you'd like to see this in context, take a look at the project video here and enable Italian subtitles:
http://tinyurl.com/y4erjs3z

I have used "managers di assunzione" there because I couldn't find a better alternative.

A professional translator wrote it like this:

> Hiring managers, you don't have the time to linearly read through
>   dozens of CVs
>       Assumere manager di cui non avete il tempo di informarvi tra dozzine di CV

but `assumere` is a verb and not a noun so it makes no sense to me.

And the other context where is used is here:

> Hiring managers, you’re on the other end.
>       Assumendo manager, avete il coltello dalla parte del manico.

but again `assumendo` is a verb and not a noun.

Comment: Welcome on ItalianSE!

Comment: I am not sure that that was the work of a “professional” translator. Whoever (or whatever translation engine) it was, they misunderstood those sentences as if they were “By hiring (some) managers, you...”.

Comment: @DaG indeed, but if you read the first quoted sentence, without the comma after 'managers' one could misunderstand the meaning as you say. 'Manager' could be the  subject or the object of the sentence, changing the meaning of 'hiring'

Comment: @clabacchio: Right, but the Italian “translation” doesn't make sense in any case. If the meaning was the other one, in Italian it would something like “Quando si assumono (dei) manager/dirigenti, non c'è tempo” etc.

Comment: @DaG indeed, the rest of the translation doesn't make sense anyway. I was focusing on the ambiguity of the english version

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A good translation could be *responsabili delle assunzioni* or *responsabili della selezione*.

More extensively you could also use the expression *responsabili della ricerca e selezione del personale* corresponding to human resources recruitment managers.

The expression *cacciatore di teste* adheres more to head hunter.

Comment: `responsabile delle assunzioni` is `responsabile` plural??

Comment: Responsabile is singular, the plural would be responsabili.

Comment: Then the correct translation would be `Responsabili delle assunzioni`

Comment: Ok, now I got my mistake... Going to correct the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In this article it is called "Gestore di Assunzione" and it is translated like this exactly:
https://it.routestofinance.com/contacting-hiring-manager-on-linkedin

Therefore, my answer would be "Gestori di Assunzione"

Answer (score -3):

It's " Assumiamo Managers " and it's better you specify for which sector, for example: Assumiamo Manager di Produzione means, we are hiring production managers.

Keep in mind that the word manager/s is used in Italian the same way as in English.

Comment: Welcome on ItalianSE!

Comment: You may have  misunderstood the context, "Assumiamo Managers" it's "We are hiring managers" (why the capital M btw?) and that isn't what the OP is asking about. Final note, while the word "manager" is understood in Italian, using it in a formal context is still frowned upon (at least in Italy). It's considered a lack of mastery of the Italian language that already has "responsabile"/"dirigente" for it.